# text contain Arabic then English words in react native(android)

Tags: android, react-native, text, cross-platform, arabic-support

The app supports both Arabic and English, and the user name can be in Arabic or English.
If the app is in English mode and user name is in Arabic , the notification is like "محمد send order" and this text in Text tag  on `iOS` is OK with `writingDirection` props , but in android was shown like " send order محمد".

Can I force Text tag in android to write "ltr" ???

simple example

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

class TextTest extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ alignContent: "center", alignSelf: "stretch", alignItems: "stretch", flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{
          fontSize: 35, alignSelf: "center", writingDirection: "ltr"
        }} >
          {"محمد play football"}
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
export default TextTest;
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s6dV.jpg): [the result in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4s6dV.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To support RTL, you need to make a few quick changes as described here [React Native Dev Blog - RTL Support](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#making-an-app-rtl-ready)

1. Make sure you have added this line in your `MainActivity.java` file

`I18nUtil sharedI18nUtilInstance = I18nUtil.getInstance();`
`sharedI18nUtilInstance.allowRTL(context, true);`

2. And add this tag in `AndroidManifest.xml` under the `<application>` root tag

`android:supportsRtl="true"`

In the same post, they've also described the [inconsistency in the default behavior for both Android and iOS for text flow](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#limitations-and-future-plan).

> Text alignment behaviors differ in Android and iOS
>   In iOS, the default text alignment depends on the active language bundle, they are consistently on one side. In Android, the default text alignment depends on the language of the text content, i.e. English will be left-aligned and Arabic will be right-aligned.

You might want to use `Platform.select` to then force the layout you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <Text style={{
      fontSize: 35, alignSelf: "center", writingDirection: "ltr"
    }} >
      {`User ${yourUserName} play football`}
    </Text>
```

*Just make your user-input that's expected to be either RTL or LTR --> embedded in your localized text*